# How to get Google Maps API key without entering billing info

Tags: google-maps

**Context**

I would like to get Google Maps API key for free usage (below 5000 per year hits), but when I follow the instructions, it seems that providing billing information is mandatory.

**Question**

What am I missing, or is it really impossible to have Google Maps on a page without providing billing info?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google's billing and terms of use, not coding

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes you need to setup a billing account, there is no way around it these days. As long as you keep under the free tier it doesn't really matter.

Also their pricing examples are counted monthly so the things that have 5 000 hits in their pricing is per month not per year.

Comment: -_- I hope they fix it.

Comment: I really doubt they will change this. They are still giving out a lot of free usage (currently equivavlent to $200/month) which is enough for a lot of small to medium sized sites and setting up a billing account just takes a few minutes.

Comment: If I remember correctly they will verify your card by making a small transaction so a fake credit card number won't work. I would suggest that you either contact Google about it or check out another map framework such as Leaflet and then use OpenStreetMap for your maps.

Comment: I got the api key for my Google Map Api but I have not enabled billing still it's working fine. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: How you got it? can you tell

Answer (score 33):

This is old but in case it helps anyone else I can still get to the following URLs without having to enter billing info

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=your-project-name

If you don't know your project name try variations of the above link (shorten it a section at a time) until you see the blue banner along the top with the pull-down name of projects. If you click the pull-down you'll see a popup with all your project names which you can use to put into the above URL.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=your-project-name
(you can get to that URL from the 'Library' menu on the left)

From here you can find and enable the API you want, e.g. https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-backend.googleapis.com?project=your-project-name (you should see a blue 'Enable' button)

You'll probably get redirected to the billing page after enabling it but ignore that - your selected API should now be enabled and if you go back to the first URL you should see it listed at the bottom of the page (but if you click on it here you'll likely get booted to the billing page again).

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=your-project-name
(you can get here from the 'Credentials' menu on left)

This is where you can set up and manage your API key - there's a link at the top to 'Add credentials'. When done they will appear listed on the page and can be edited by clicking on the name of the API key in the list or the 'Actions' > 'Edit API key' triple dot on the right of the list, plus other actions you might need.

So it's possible to enable an API and create a key for it, but I don't know if it still needs billing info as I can't get it working... but that might be my limited coding skills ;)

Comment: The process works for me, but then when I post a request, the response {... "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}. Unfortunately.

Comment: "This API project is not authorized to use this API."

Comment: similar to KeithWM, it worked for me too but when I tried to access it on my application it throws error on the browser console "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project".

Answer (score 11):

You can use iframe tag instead api-key without any problem.

```html
<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Tangesir%20Dates%20Products&amp;t=&amp;z=13&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed" width=300 height=150 allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: is there any way we can setup the cordinates of the pin pointer in maps

Comment: This is only really working solution in 2021

Comment: However this solution only shows a snapshot of the location and is not really a map. You need to click on it order to get you to the real google maps site that has scrolling, zoom etc

Comment: Yes you can set cordinates of the pin pointer in maps, for example : https://www.google.com/maps/@28.9911499,50.8781685,17.13z

Answer (score 2):

It is still possible to enable Maps API without billing, but it has to be done through the Cloud SDK console.

Details of how this is done is given here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key#gcloud-api-keys-create

**Update 2023:**
This method no longer works properly. Using it will now result in watermarks on the map.

Comment: Text above it says - 
Before you start using the Maps Embed API, you need a project with a *billing account* and the Maps Embed API enabled. To learn more, see Set up in Cloud Console.

Comment: @ShashankBhatt When I posted my answer, that text didn't exist. Were you able to verify if it is still possible?

Comment: We are already able to create api key but then map is coming with watermarks of development purpose only. that is the issue.